# PCB Pad Replacement Help!

Tags: pcb, soldering

I am a novice hobbyist who destroyed a few solder pads while trying to remove a component on a small circuit board and need some assistance with repairing them. According to my research, you can purchase replacement pads online and either solder them in place or use some sort of epoxy to hold the pad down.
My question is what is the preferred method and is there a specific type of solder I should use (Lead vs unleaded).

Here is a picture of the pads I need to replace:

[image: Close-up]

[image: Close-up different angle]

Comment: Solder thin wires (the ones using for wire-wrapping circuits for example) to restore the broken connections. then fix them in place using kapton tape.

Comment: There looks to be quite a bit of damage on that board- traces overheated from the failure? You can fix this with jumper wires and epoxy but it will take care and some skill and time. Might be worth considering getting local help if the board is at all valuable.

Comment: I have not ever had any success trying to replace the existing pads or using those "stick-on" pads.  The only way I've had any luck with is just using wire-wrap or similar wire and directly soldering from point to point to replace the missing pads and traces.  I've found that hot glue works well to secure things after you get it fixed electrically.

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, clean up everything burnt and damaged with isopropyl. Apart from burn marks, there's also some mess on the right side of the second picture (maybe just flux residue?).
- Usually broken pads are fixed by scratching off the nearby solder mask from the trace using a scalpel, then solder a thin wire onto the exposed copper. Isolated wire if needed, it would be 0.25mm/AWG30 something like that, maybe even thinner. Keep wires tightly against the board, apply hot glue or silicone to keep it in place when done.
- It seems you have extensive board damage elsewhere - a whole net seems to have overheated and burnt off the solder mask. At heat like that something will have given in and burnt off. You need to verify that all traces are still intact - repairing this might not be trivial, if at all possible. Also looks like burn damage underneath one of the LEDs(?). Any component located on this trace might be damaged.
- You have a cold joint beneath the LM7808 which needs to be redone. Apply flux then heat it up proper, using a flat solder tip.